# Visual Studio Code training YOLO models using CPU

Tags: visual-studio-code, gpu

I would like to ask the ways to enable GPU for model trainings in my Visual Studio Code.

Here is the image of it running my CPU to full 100% without utilizing my GPU.

[image]

I've enabled the settings for GPU hardware acceleration in VS Code.

I've enabled the 'High Performance' settings in my laptop's graphic settings for VS Code.

But it is still training the model using my CPU.

Most of the solutions given by google and youtube are just enabling the High Performance setting, which I've done as mentioned above.

Any suggestions would help, thanks in advance!!

Comment: you should configure python to use the GPU, VSC GPU is for the GUI